# Repeating Data In Access Combo Box

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access-2010

I am having an issue regarding repeating data in my access form, I want to be able to select a tutors name and for it to display all of the students linked to that tutor this does work however in the list view because one tutor sees many students the data is repeated (see images) Is there a SQL statement I should be using to stop this?  (I am new to Access and SQLServer so I apologies if this is an obvious)  Please see the images below which will make my issue clear.

[image: acess]
[image: sql]
[image: relationships]

Comment: can you include your query for Tutors? how are you selecting Tutors

Comment: Hi here is the query from access for the combo box SELECT "Tutors"."PAT" FROM "Tutors";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by adding SELECT 'DISTINCT' to my SQL Statement so from

```
SELECT "Tutors"."PAT" FROM "Tutors";
```

To:

```
SELECT DISTINCT "Tutors"."PAT" FROM "Tutors";
```